# Схема работы с клиентом при WordPress-разработке

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я знаю, как работать с темами  и плагинами, как менять их и устанавливать, знаю как натягивать верстку на WordPress, немного знаю работу с файлами.

Зашел на фриланс (любой), вижу там заказы, ну вот вроде смогу у себя выполнить на локальном хосте (у меня локальный хост, но знаю как установить сайт на хостинг), но не знаю как он сможет мне сайт передать, как грамотней это сделать.

Пожалуйста, если вам не сложно, распишите по пунктам с примерами, как происходит работа с заказчиком. На примере заказа, где надо человеку сделать интернет магазин из верстки которую он сам натянул, установить плагины и установить на хостинг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не волнуйтесь, всё с опытом приходит.

Обычно разработка в вашем случае идет примерно так:

**1) Делаем всё локально.**

Поднимаете у себя полноценный WordPress-сайт, устанавливаете все нужные плагины, натянутый шаблон заказчика. От заказчика вам нужна просто папка с шаблоном. Ну, возможно, список произвольных полей, которые нужно создать, чтобы шаблон работал корректно.

**2) Показываем результат**

Когда все готово - показываете результаты заказчику на своем тестовом сервере или сразу переносите к нему, если есть доверие к клиенту.

Есть вариант показать и локальный сайт. Вот сервисы, которые в этом помогут:

- http://localtunnel.me/
- https://ngrok.com/
- http://localhost.run/

**3) Переносим сайт**

Если все окей - окончательно переносите сайт к клиенту на хостинг и передаете ему файлы, базу и т.д.

О том, как переносить сайт правильно читайте в ответе [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress)

Comment: Спасибо,у меня есть  к вам вопрос,каким способом лучше показать сайт на локальном хосте клиенту ?

Comment: Есть сервисы, которые позволяют вашему локальному серверу "смотреть в мир". Вы получаете временную ссылку, которую и можете показать заказчику.

Вот такие сервисы:

http://localtunnel.me/
https://ngrok.com/
http://localhost.run/

Answer (score 0):

Разрабатывать сайт нужно в той среде, где он будет работать. Т.е. на реальном хостинге, а не на всяких виндовых недосерверах. Только так можно всё нормально оттестировать. Кроме того, это избавит от многих проблем с миграцией, а также обеспечит и безопасность и простоту взаимодействия с заказчиком.

При работе с заказчиком возможны варианты:

1. У заказчика нет ничего и сайт создаётся с нуля.
2. У заказчика уже есть работающий сайт, который нужно доделать или переделать.

В первом случае сайт можно создавать сразу на нужном домене.
Во втором стоит использовать технический домен. Я для этого испольную либо бесплатные либо прописав реальный в [host](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts) в зависимости от квалификации заказчика.
**Замечание**: не стоит использовать поддомены, тк при миграции могут возникнуть проблемы.

После окончания работ сайт мигрирует на хостинг заказчика и производится окончательная доработка - включение индексации, сеошные настройки и тестирование-анализ работы уже на хостинге клиента.

Правильные способы миграции описаны в [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561)
Всяческие советы произвести изменения непосредственно в базе являются опасными и чреваты поломкой сайта. Если не сразу, то в будущем.

Answer (score -1):

Ну, чтобы передать сайт заказчику вам надо:

```
1) Передать заказчику папку с ВП
2) Передать БД, ведь в неё все данные о сайте и страницах
```

Первое передать легко и просто - складываете папку с ВП в архив(`.rar`,`.zip` и тд) и отправляете заказчику.

Второе надо передать БД. Это делается путём сохранения дампа бд([тут пример с phpMyAdmin](https://jino.ru/help/faq/phpmyadmin/db-export/)), а затем заказчик [экспортирует БД](https://ru.godaddy.com/help/kak-eksportirovat-bazy-dannyh-mysql-1487) и меняет [домен](https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/spravka-po-cms/perenos-sayta-na-wordpress-s-odnogo-domena-na-drugoy)

Ну, это основные трудности, с которыми лично я столкнулся

Comment: скажите,а как заказчик передает мне сайт,к примеру я смотрел по этому информацию,и там писалось про какие то права,что заказчик боится что могут сайт украсть и так далее.Можете подсказать что за ограниченные права может дать заказчик ?

Comment: @misterwordpress, это делается на самом сайте ВП. Когда вы создаёте сайт сами, то вы вбиваете свои данные для аккаунта, после чего входител в `wp-admin` и управляете сайтом. Тоже самое можно сделать, но с ограниченными правами. То есть, главный аккаунт создаёт новый профиль во вкладке "Пользователи" и даёт вам доступ только к некоторым функциям. Например: "редактор" - вы можете добавлять/удалять посты, добавлять файлы скачки и тд. То есть, это настраивается уже по вкусу заказчика)